# What is the correct syntax for combining a regular expression stored in a variable with a quantifier?

Tags: python, regex

I know there's a lot of questions in stack overflow already about using a variable in regular expression, and I managed to make it work if the variable is one word, or if it only needs to match once; however, once I add both a special character/whitespace and a quantifier, I can't get it to match. For example, I want to match whatever is in *some_var* to any string that contains 3 consecutive copies of it.:

```
import re

some_var = "what what"

should_match = "what what what what what what hey"
not_a_match = "what what what what hey what what"

match = re.search(re.escape(some_var){3}, should_match)
no_match = re.search(re.escape(some_var){3}, not_a_match)
```

however the last two lines give me a syntax error, and I've tried

```
'(.*)'+re.escape(some_var){3}+'(.*)'
('(.*)'+re.escape(some_var)+'(.*)'){3}
'(.*)'+'re.escape(some_var){3}'+'(.*)'
're.escape(some_var){3}'
```

... I just can't seem to get the syntax for it to match correctly (I keep getting the false conditional). I've tried searching for the answer, but I'm not sure how to get it to recognize the quantifier properly.

Comment: Construct it using string catenation like this `'(.*)(?:'+re.escape(some_var)+'){3}(.*)'` In other words, the regex part's are actual string parts.

Comment: But, you will potentially run into edge problems if you do it all at once this way. Its too long to expalain, but if you expect whitespace separation, it hast to have a begin and an end, i.e., `some_var(?:\s+some_var){2}` Otherwise, you will be chasing your tail.

Comment: @sln could you perhaps provide an example edge case I can test/work with? Regex is still very new to me so I'm still digesting that (?...) syntax and I'm unable to think of an edge case to test. Thank you!

Comment: It's the premise of `3 consecutive copies` that is the problem. To have 3 copies of anything, there is 2 middle borderless boundaries. That means `should_match = "what whatwhat whatwhat what"`. Because to you it looks like a space is invisible, you think it should match, but _all_ text is binary codes that occupy real bytes in memory. Typically, if you want to allow different separator boundaries, it is done like I posted. This is for consistency. `(?:\s*some_var){3}` is a hack, especially made to match your inconsistent problem. In the real world, it's not done this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to group that several words and add optional whitespace:

```
match = re.search(r"(?:\s*{0}){{3}}".format(re.escape(some_var)), should_match)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/R1AVw1)

The regex will look like `(?:\s*what\ what){3}`, and [this is how it works](https://regex101.com/r/cE6qW1/1): it matches 3 sequences of

- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace followed by
- `what\ what` - literal `what what` substring.

Comment: There is an edge condition problem.

Comment: thank you! this problem has been bugging me for hours! and thank you for providing info on how it works, otherwise that would have definitely been my next question :)

Comment: You are welcome. I just want to add that in case you want to *extract* the value, you can use `match.group().strip()` to get rid of any "wild" leading whitespace.

Comment: @Melissa: Glad it worked for you. Please consider also upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) since you now have this privilege.

Comment: @stribizhev done and done :) for `match.group().strip()`, does that take care [some?] of the edge cases @sln mentioned?

Comment: @Melissa: sure. All of them.

Answer (score 1):

Regex patterns are just strings (with any non-alphanumerics backslash escaped to match a literal string), so you can either use `format` or `%` operator or concatenation to create the pattern string you need.

Given some value of `n` as a quantifier, in this case 3, you need to construct the regex string appropriately. The `{3}` part needs to be in the pattern string immediately following the `re.escape(some_var)`.

You can use the `%` operator:

```
>>> n=3
>>> r'(?:\s*%s){%i}' % (re.escape(some_var), n)
'(?:\\s*what\\ what){3}'
```

Or, use `format`:

```
>>> r'(?:\s*{0}){{{1}}}'.format(re.escape(some_var), n)
'(?:\\s*what\\ what){3}'
```

Or use concatenation:

```
>>> r'(?:\s*'+re.escape(some_var)+'){'+str(n)+'}'
'(?:\\s*what\\ what){3}'
```

Any of these strings will now work as you think:

```
>>> re.match(r'(?:\s*%s){%i}' % (re.escape(some_var), n), should_match)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x104244b28>
>>> re.match(r'(?:\s*%s){%i}' % (re.escape(some_var), n), not_a_match)
>>>
```

Comment: thank you! I realized I was concatenating incorrectly. seems like I was mainly missing the (?: ) syntax (I tried .format() and % formatting and still got syntax errors with the way I was writing the regex)